# How do I map a mouse's scroll wheel to up and down array keys in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, xorg, mouse, scrolling

I'd like to scroll through previous commands or scroll through a text editor with the scroll wheel. I don't know how to do this without starting a full-blown X Window System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straightforward.

It is however possible using a bit of programming to make a command line filter to prove the concept. For instance in Python (see below).

This filter would take the standard input (i.e. your keyboard) and pass it on to standard output. It must also capture mouse data and when it sees scroll wheel data add arrow up or down to standard out.

You can capture mouse output on /dev/input/mouse (or mouse0 or mouse1)

You then start it as:

```
sudo ./filter.py | bash
```

A crude, working concept is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fcntl
import os
import sys

# make stream a non-blocking file
f = open('/dev/input/mouse0')
fd = f.fileno()
fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while (True):
    key = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(key)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    try:
        mouse = f.read(1)
        sys.stdout.write('date\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    except:
        continue
```

It will execute all commands you enter (no prompt though) and when you move the mouse, and then hit enter it will execute the 'date' command.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the right way to go. I'll have to play around with this a bit to meet my needs.